# HAProxy not forwarding requests

Tags: haproxy

I've this config file:-

```
frontend http80
        bind *:80
        timeout client 60s
        mode http
        use_backend allservers

backend allservers
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout server 60s
        mode http
        server server3000 127.0.0.1:3000
```

But this doesn't work,
When I try to access like `<myIP>:3000` It works perfectly.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Do you get any errors? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: @HolgerJust Its just getting timeout.